# tkinter white space when using columnspan

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class QuizInterface:
    def __init__(self, quiz: QuizBrain):
        self.quiz = quiz
        # setting windows
        self.window = tk.Tk()

        self.window.title = 'Quiz'
        self.window.config(bg=THEME_COLOR, padx=20, pady=20)
        # setting the frames
        self.f1 = tk.Frame(self.window)
        self.f2 = tk.Frame(self.window)

        for frame in (self.f1, self.f2):
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

        # setting f2
        tk.Label(self.f2, text='number of questions', bg=THEME_COLOR,
                 fg='white', font=('Arial', 15, 'normal')).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

        self.radio_state = tk.IntVar()
        self.r10 = tk.Radiobutton(self.f2, bg=THEME_COLOR,
                                  text="10", value=10, variable=self.radio_state, command=self.radio_used)
        self.r25 = tk.Radiobutton(self.f2, bg=THEME_COLOR,
                                  text="25", value=25, variable=self.radio_state, command=self.radio_used)
        self.r50 = tk.Radiobutton(self.f2, bg=THEME_COLOR,
                                  text="50", value=50, variable=self.radio_state, command=self.radio_used)
        self.r10.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='EW')
        self.r25.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='EW')
        self.r50.grid(row=1, column=2)


        self.window.mainloop()
```

This is my code. I've cut out some from it, but this is the part where it's causing the problem.

[image: here is a picture of it]

as you can see, there is a white empty space between option 25 and option 50. I found out that columnspan of the Label affects this. Why is this happening, and how can this be resolved? Thanks in advance.

edit: I found out that it may be caused by the radiobuttons overlapping with each other. But still don't know the solution

Answer (score 1):

Just tweak your last radio button placement and add a sticky attribute to that too:

```
self.r50.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='EW')
```

So that the third one also fills its column

Comment: I did as you wrote. Resolved the problem for that radiobutton. Now another widget I made also has the white spaces too...

Comment: sticky should make the new offending widget also fill the space, just make sure to add it to the correct side of the widget and make sure you're adding it to the right widget

Comment: @siyunlee Then update the question with it